# How to sort cron expressions in typescript?

Tags: typescript, sorting, cron

I am working on an angularjs application, and I need to sort in ascending order a list of jobs by schedule attribute (which is a cron expression that could be hourly, daily, monthly, quarterly, yearly, etc),
Example:

```
[
  0: object{ schedule: '0 0 2 * * ?' },
  1: object{ schedule: '0 0 10 * * ? '},
  2: object{ schedule: '0 0 23 * * ? ' },
  3: object{ schedule: '0 0 20 * * ? ' },
  4: object{ schedule: '0 0 3 * * ? ' },
  5: object{ schedule: '0 55 * * * ? ' }
]
```

What i want to achieve:

```
[
  0: object{ schedule: '0 55 * * * ? ' },
  1: object{ schedule: '0 0 2 * * ?' },
  2: object{ schedule: '0 0 3 * * ? ' },
  3: object{ schedule: '0 0 10 * * ? '},
  4: object{ schedule: '0 0 20 * * ? ' },
  5: object{ schedule: '0 0 23 * * ? ' }
]
```

I already use [cronstrue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cronstrue) library to make cron expressions more human readable, , i thought about parsing the expressions and manually sort them , but it turned out to have many edge cases to handle, any suggestions how to achieve sorting of a list of cron jobs in typescript ?

Comment: Note this would be a *JavaScript* task, as it would be happening at runtime.

Comment: This seems an impossible task without the constraints of a time window and evaluating all the permutations within it. You would potentially have 1 entry generating several times within a window of time.